# Changing the acceptance key (autosuggest-accept) - ZSH shell on mac

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

on > `zsh` `mac` `terminal`
if i type `c` and get the autocompletion suggestion as `clear`

To accept that suggestion i need to hit right arrow key and  then press enter to run it.
I want to change the right arrow key to something else for example **`** OR **'**

Plese help on finding a way to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change bindkey for *autosuggest-accept* widget.

```
bindkey '`' autosuggest-accept
```

Note that this will disable your ability to type ` character directly though.
If you want to execute the autosuggest immediately after hitting `, change `autosuggest-accept` to `autosuggest-execute`.

To make this change permanent, add the bindkey line to your ~/.zshrc

If you also want to disable arrow key, you can remove the widget from `ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS` array.

```
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS=("${(@)ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS:#forward-char}")
```

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. Thank you very much for saving my time and finger muscle pain :)

Answer (score 4):

As a more *out-of-the-box* solution, I just found out [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/532) that you can use:

```
CTRL+E
```

instead of the right arrow, and it will accept the autosuggestion.

*In the link they refer to it as "end-of-line in emacs mode", but I didn't configure anything of the sort, so I guess it just works.*